# Generate date ranges using group by + apply in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date

I want to imitate prophet make_future_dataframe() functionality for multiple groups in a pandas dataframe.

If I would like to create a date range as a separate column I could do:

```
import pandas as pd
my_dataframe['prediction_range'] = pd.date_range(start=my_dataframe['date_column'].min(),
                                           periods=48,
                                           freq='M')
```

However my dataframe has the following structure:

```
id feature1 feature2 date_column
1     0         4.3    2022-01-01
2     0         3.3    2022-01-01
3     0         2.2    2022-01-01
4     1034      1.11   2022-01-01
5     1090      0.98   2022-01-01
6     1078      0      2022-01-01
```

I wanted to do the following:

```
def generate_date_range(date_column, data):
    dates = pd.date_range(start=data[date_column].unique()[0],
                    periods=48,
                    freq='M')
    return dates
```

And then:

```
my_dataframe = my_dataframe.groupby('id').apply(generate_date_ranges('date_columns', my_dataframe))
```

But I am getting the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/anaconda/envs/scoring_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 1377, in apply
    func = com.is_builtin_func(func)
  File "/anaconda/envs/scoring_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/common.py", line 615, in is_builtin_func
    return _builtin_table.get(arg, arg)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'DatetimeIndex'
```

I am not sure if I am approaching the problem in the right way. I have also done this with a MultiIndex:

```
multi_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([pd.Index(file['id'].unique()), dates], names=('customer', 'prediction_date'))
```

And then reindexing an filling the NANs but I am not able to understand why the apply version does not work.

The desired output is:

```
    id feature1 feature2 date_column prediction_date
    1     0         4.3    2022-01-01 2022-03-01
    1     0         4.3    2022-01-01 2022-04-01
    1     0         4.3    2022-01-01 2022-05-01
    1     0         4.3    2022-01-01 2022-06-01
--- Up to 48 periods --
    2     0         3.3    2022-01-01 2022-03-01
    2     0         3.3    2022-01-01 2022-04-01
    2     0         3.3    2022-01-01 2022-05-01
    2     0         3.3    2022-01-01 2022-06-01
```

BR
E

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: I have added the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing some list comprehension on your groupby object where you reindex the dates then forward fill the id

```
df['date_column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_column'])
df = df.set_index('date_column')

new_df = pd.concat([g.reindex(pd.date_range(g.index.min(), periods=48, freq='MS'))
                for _,g in df.groupby('id')])

new_df['id'] = new_df['id'].ffill().astype(int)

            id  feature1  feature2
2022-01-01   1       0.0       4.3
2022-02-01   1       NaN       NaN
2022-03-01   1       NaN       NaN
2022-04-01   1       NaN       NaN
2022-05-01   1       NaN       NaN
...         ..       ...       ...
2025-08-01   6       NaN       NaN
2025-09-01   6       NaN       NaN
2025-10-01   6       NaN       NaN
2025-11-01   6       NaN       NaN
2025-12-01   6       NaN       NaN
```

## Update

If there is only one record for each ID we can do the following. If there is more than one record for each ID then we will need to only keep the min value for each ID, preform the task below and merge everything back together.

```
# make sure your date is datetime
df['date_column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_column'])

# use index.repeat for the number of months you want
# in this case we will offset the min date for 48 months
new_df = df.reindex(df.index.repeat(48)).reset_index(drop=True)

# groupby the id, cumcount and set the type so we can offset
new_df['date_column'] = new_df['date_column'].values.astype('datetime64[M]') + \
new_df.groupby('id')['date_column'].cumcount().values.astype('timedelta64[M]')



     id  feature1  feature2 date_column
0     1         0       4.3  2022-01-01
1     1         0       4.3  2022-02-01
2     1         0       4.3  2022-03-01
3     1         0       4.3  2022-04-01
4     1         0       4.3  2022-05-01
..   ..       ...       ...         ...
283   6      1078       0.0  2025-08-01
284   6      1078       0.0  2025-09-01
285   6      1078       0.0  2025-10-01
286   6      1078       0.0  2025-11-01
287   6      1078       0.0  2025-12-01
```

Comment: Hi Chris, is there a faster way to do that than with a foor loop? I have around 222k ids so as you can image the code is still running since I launched.

Comment: Is there only one date value for each id or are there multiple? In other words, are there multiple records for each id or only one like your example?

Comment: Hi Chris, in the original dataset there is only one record per id. However after adding the dates I expect to have 48 records per id. Does this make sense?

Comment: Correct, Did you see my update to the answer?

Comment: Now yes! Working like charm Chris.

Thank you!

Comment: Great, glad it is working. The update should be significantly faster.

Comment: Indeed it is, I have also tried to make this with a join and a .fillna but your method seems the faster so fast.